# How does a code with redundant lines run faster than a code without them?

Tags: c++, algorithm, compiler-optimization

I just started leetcoding, and I solved a problem called "Move Zeroes": https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/

I came up with a solution for this problem. I'll refer to the code below as "Code A".

```
class Solution {
public:
    void moveZeroes(vector<int>& nums) {
        int cnt_zero = 0, cnt_nonzero = 0;
        int len = nums.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            if(nums[i] == 0)
                cnt_zero++;
            else {
                nums[cnt_nonzero++] = nums[i];
            }
        }
        for(int i = cnt_nonzero; i < len; ++i)
            nums[i] = 0;
    }
};
```

Then, I realized that I don't have to maintain cnt_zero, and wrote "Code B", as displayed below.

```
class Solution {
public:
    void moveZeroes(vector<int>& nums) {
        int cnt_nonzero = 0;
        int len = nums.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            if(nums[i] != 0) {
                nums[cnt_nonzero++] = nums[i];
            }
        }
        for(int i = cnt_nonzero; i < len; ++i)
            nums[i] = 0;
    }
};
```

However, Code A got a result of : *0ms runtime, 9MB memory use* while Code B got a result of : *8ms runtime, 8.9MB memory use*. Why is Code B slower than Code A?

Comment: I once encountered an example where a very complicated if statement ran faster on an IBM processor, turned out the simple if statement cooled the CPU and it ran slower. Processors are man-made yet complicated. This doesn't answer your question, but gives a perspective of how counter-intuitive things can get.

Comment: The normal way to measure code performance involves running it numerous times, and building up statistics.   If some section of code takes a few millisecond to run (with a specified inputs),  jitter of more than 8 msec is typical with modern systems.    In other words, your measurement uncertainty is greater than the maximum of the two runtimes you are measuring.

Comment: [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition).

Comment: Since in your code cnt_zero isn't used, most compilers will generate exactly the same code for both of your solutions, see: https://godbolt.org/z/aGqMWGr5W
Generated assembly looks exactly the same for both. That gives even more rationale, that difference you noticed is just jitter due to measurement uncertainty.

Comment: `std::remove` + `std::fill` and done.

Comment: Telling people to use `std::` features when they are trying to understand and optimize their own code is not helping. But yeah, the trick here would be to compare many runs on very long vectors. I'd expect no difference between A and Be.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://quick-bench.com/q/4N7_FGbGQ3khEaXgu-RjLKCWrMM

Comment: @Scheff'sCat you have provided broken link (diff is empty), Fixed version: https://godbolt.org/z/TWo3qK1Ys

Comment: @MarekR It wasn't when I posted the link. :-( Thanks, anyway.